# Dart : how to check if entered strings contains only spaces or specials chars with RegEX

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check for my text field that user should not enter all special characters or should not add all spaces. It should be a combination of Alpha numberic (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) and special characters in text field. I can add spaces but not all spaces. How I will do with regEx?